# "Hard disk not found" after attempted install Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, installation, dualboot

I had a dual boot system with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 22.04. I wanted to install Ubuntu 23.10 instead of 22.04.

**Info**:

- Secure boot: off
- SATA mode: AHCI
- Boot mode: UEFI

Windows and Linux are both installed on the same internal M2 PCIe SSD

These are the steps I followed, and always have followed, when installing a new version.

1. Create bootable Ubuntu USB (tried both the newest and legacy installer version)
2. Boot into live session using UEFI mode
3. Manual partitioning:

- Set /dev/nvmen0p1 with mount option /boot/efi, make sure not to format
- Set /dev/nvmen0p6 with mount point /, make sure to format
- Set /dev/nvmen0p7 with mount point /home, make sure not to format

4. Proceed with installation.

In my attempt to install Ubuntu 23.10 I never made it to step #4. The installation process this time showed issues become the changes in step #3 where not reflected (not reflecting what I just configured). I tried restarting but faced a DELL bios message: "Harddisk not found", when continuering after this message then DELL does something (most likely attempt to recover, but this goes way to quick too see what's happening) reatarts and boots into Windows.

I tried booting back into live session and checked with gparted and fdisk the SSD. Gparted won't see the disk consistently when it does it shows the partitions and marks the SSD as "nvmen0 - 0B" (As in zero bytes). Fdisk /dev/nvmen0 gets me permission denied. lsblk shows me the disk and partitions from time to time.

In tried repeating these steps multiple times. Sometimes the Ubuntu installer sees the disk, but I cannot make changes (partitions keeping disappearing randomly or removed partitions suddenly show ups again when managing the partition layout)

Again, I never got to step #4 were these changes actually applied. In see one pattern though: Everytime When I see the disk in the Ubuntu installer, after reboot the message: "Harddisk not found" pops up and continues as described earlier and always succesfully boots into Windows. Also when the disk is not visible in the installer, restarting and booting into l windows let me see it most of the times.

I used the Dell diagnostic tools to do a thorough system diagnosis, all seems fine. SSD appears to be in good health.

I also rechecked the BIOS settings. They are still as listed above.

I am afraid my SSD is dying, but the diagnostic results and being able boot into Windows leaves me with a small bit of hope that it is a software issue.

Any advise on verifying my SSD health or any things/steps left to check/try to resolve the issue are more than welcome!!!

Comment: I found a workaround, I guess there is a compatibility issue in 23.10 installation procedure. I downloaded the Ubuntu image of the version that was currently installed (22.04). This installation procedure had no issue with my SSD and worked perfectly. After installation I did a dist-upgrade to 23.10